# Rendering static images in DXA CSS

Tags: dxa

I have a DXA WebApp with an Images folder int he Visual Studio solution.  These images are referenced in the CSS design.  However, when I try to access the URL of one of the images, like `http://localhost:55511/images/alert.gif`, I have an error message like

> Item '/images/alert.gif' not found for Localization '11'

Is it possible to store the images only in the Visual Studio Project (not in Tridion) and render them from DXA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible and I think your folder name is causing problems for you. Try changing your folder name in Visual Studio from `Images` to something different(`StaticAssets`) and give a try.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!  Didn't know that 'images' was a bad word for static assets :)

Comment: 'Images' is not a bad word, actually you have set the image path, image url values as 'Images' in the publication properties which caused the content delivery to look against the publication and ended up with exception  - not found for Localization '11'. As a workaround, you can also change the publication properties and keep 'Images' as visual studio folder